# How should I handle not yet having received a response to my email on my salary negotiation?

Tags: professionalism, salary

I have an offer from one of my favorite companies, but the new salary is just 10% above my current salary and the role may be somewhat difficult and consist of tough tasks which were previously done by 8 employees.

I would be more comfortable if we could settle on about 5% more than the current offer. I feel the new amount reflects the importance and expectations of the position for the company, and my qualifications, and experience as they relate to this particular position.

I have sent email saying that am happy with the offer but would like to discuss the base salary component, describe my experience, and why am I suited for the role and all of these qualities contribute directly to the core competency of this particular position, and that's why I'm excited for the opportunity to work with [Mr. New Manager].

There is no answer from the company afterwards. What can I do now?

Comment: Before how many days you sent email?

Comment: Apart from salary: If 8 people before you resigned, what makes you think that you as the 9th will be successful? Statistics says that either you are a hero, or you will be the 9th to resign as well.

Comment: @Nebr the way I see it is that OP is going to perform a task/multiple tasks that previously were assigned to a team of 8 people.

Comment: @EdwinLambregts After the edit of the question, I agree with you.

Comment: The best thing you could do is get another offer, preferably one that pays more.  When there are more people interested in your services, the bid price always goes up--it's simple economics.

Answer (score 3):

There are several things you should do:

Firstly, you should keep interviewing for new positions until you have a signed offer in hand that you're happy to accept.

Secondly, since the email you've sent has not garnered a response, you should pick up a phone and call the person you were emailing directly. When one form of communication like email fails, you should switch to a more direct form, which in this case means either calling them or physically going to visit them. Since going to visit is not appropriate here, you should call.

When you call them, make sure that you've decided your position on the issue: are you unwilling to accept less than the amount you're asking for, or would you be willing to accept less since the opportunity of working in this company appeals enough that you could accept less? If you are unwilling to accept a lesser amount, you need to make it clear that you're willing to walk away from the offer if you don't get the requested amount. If you're not really willing to walk away from the offer, be prepared to accept the lower amount.